# Segmented lists - problem with rules

Tags: xconnect, exm, segmented-list

has anyone of you already worked with segmented lists?

We have the problem that sometimes the rules are executed and sometimes not. We implemented a custom rule, which checks values in a custom facet of the contacts. But also it happens when it comes to using the standard rules from Sitecore like getting the preferred language.  ("where the contact's preferred language is case insensitive and equal to de-DE").

In our local environment the rules are executed correctly - but only if we use "de-DE" and not "de-de" even if it is case insensitve.

But on our integration system (Content Management plus Content Delivery) it doesn't matter. It seems that the rules are not executed.

Do you have any hint on this? 
We published the rules, we checked Xconnect running, XConnect services running, rebuilded XConnect Index, checked database.

We are thankful for every hint!

Best regards, 
Anna

Comment: Have you deployed marketing definitions from the control panel as well?

Comment: Yes we did, did it again yesterday, but still the same problem.